# Locking to Portrait on app launching rotates from Landscape to Portrait (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to lock the orientation of the first screen of the app to portrait. In some screens, I need landscape orientation. I am using the [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) plugin. But when I launch the application, I see landscape orientation for a while and then quickly rotating to portrait orientation. The next screens are ok.

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
}
```

Is it possible to solve this performance issue?

Comment: do you want to disable the landscape orientation for all screens in your app?

Comment: @Nino9612 No, in some screens I need landscape orientation.

Comment: hmm okay. For which platforms are you developing?

Comment: @Nino9612 For iOS and Android. But this problem is only in iOS.

Comment: Have you tried `Orientation.lockToPortrait()` outside of component lifecycle method may be at `app.js`?

Comment: @Prasun This was exactly my last attempt to put it in constructor of app.js, but it didn't help.

Comment: May be not even in constructor, just before you declare the app class.

Comment: @Prasun It didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my error.
I used in one class redundant code:

```
const setLandscapeRightOrientation = Platform.select({
    ios: Orientation.lockToLandscapeRight(),
    android: Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your page where orientation lock is delayed:

```
componentWillMount(){
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
}

_orientationDidChange(orientation) {    
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();  
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // remove listener
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
}
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) no longer seems maintained.

I encourage you to use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) which also provides `Orientation.lockToPortrait()`

Comment: Result is the same as with  react-native-orientation.

Comment: what is your device ? what is your OS version number ?

Comment: My device is iPhone SE. iOS 12.0.1.